# Python Code Text Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
player_health = 100

power = 10

enemy_health = 50

player_name = input('What is your name, Guardian? ')

print('Hello ' + player_name + ' the Guardian')

player_element = input('Would you like to be the Guardian of Air, Earth, Fire or Water? ')

if player_element == 'Air':
    print('You have been granted the powers of the Air, Guardian.\
          You now have the powers of the Wind and Sky.')

if player_element == 'Earth':
    print('You have been granted the powers of the Earth, Guardian.\
          You now have the powers of the Earth.')

if player_element == 'Fire':
    print('You have been granted the powers of Fire, Guardian.\
          You now have the powers of Fire. Do not destroy as you wish.')

if player_element == 'Water':
    print('You have been granted the powers of Water, Guardian.\
          You now have the powers to control the oceans and water.')

print('There is an enemy in the distance! What do you do?')

player_action = input('What do you do ' + player_name + '? ' + 'Type A to attack ')

if player_action == 'A':
    print('The enemy\'s health is at ' + enemy_health + '! ' 'Keep attacking Guardian!')

enemy_health = print(enemy_health - power)
```

In the last block of code, I want it to print out `The enemy's health is at 40`!(because `power - enemy_health = 40`) `Keep attacking Guardian!'`
Any tips?
It gets the error of `cant convert int object to str` implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate a string with an integer, instead you can use `format`

```
print('The enemy\'s health is at {}! Keep attacking Guardian!'.format(enemy_health))
```

For you to use the `+` operator and perform concatenation, you'd first have to create a string first

```
print('The enemy\'s health is at ' + str(enemy_health) + '! Keep attacking Guardian!'
```

You also need to actually modify their health, I'm not sure what you think this is doing

```
enemy_health = print(enemy_health - power)
```

You should change that to

```
enemy_health = enemy_health - power
```

Comment: but when i run the code its says the enemys health is at 50. i want it to say 40. Also does .format like reset that variable?

Comment: Hmm yes you can.. str(35)+"Hello". Is a string because of the explicit conversion

Comment: @FirebladeDan .... which is why I said *"You cannot concatenate a string with an integer"*. In your example you are concatenating a `str` with a `str`. I don't see what point you are trying to make.

Comment: @CoryKramer - You are being over technical. Because what if this young kid gets a test question that asks "Can you concatenate a string and an integer?" Technically No which is what you're saying but the right answer is "Yes" by explicitly converting using str()...

Comment: I am being **very deliberate** in my wording, because in programming you must be **very deliberate** with the operations you are performing between types. Which led the OP to have the issue they are posting about.

Comment: Which is why in my next sentence I said *"For you to use the + operator and perform concatenation, you'd first have to create a string first"*

Comment: guys please don't fight. i just want an answer to perform a simple sentence that do not know how to do myself

Comment: @ShaneFernandes Did you look at my answer? I literally told you how to fix your issue.

Comment: Sir, it does not work it prints out as 'The enemy's health is at 50! ... and then prints out 40. The second one prints out 'The enemy's health is at enemy_health...'

Answer (score 0):

```
enemy_health = enemy_health - power
```

Reassign your `enemy_health` variable to be their current `health-power`. Then you can reuse this integer anywhere by explicitly converting using `str(enemy_health)`. PythonMaster & CoryKramer have the newest implementation which is using `.format()`. These `{}` indicate where the variable from the format list should be placed.

```
print(str(enemy_health))
```

Comment: This works but it just prints out 40 in the end I want 'The enemy's health is at 40! Keep attacking Guardian!'

Comment: Yup I want you to see what I did here.

Comment: I did but its not what i wanted but still useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.format()` instead because you cannot concatenate a string with an integer. Try instead:

```
print('The enemy\'s health is at {}! Keep attacking Guardian!'.format(enemy_health))
```

or the much less complex way:

```
enemy_health -= power  #This is short for enemy_health = enemy_health - power
print("The enemy's health is at", enemy_health,"! Keep attacking Guardian!")
```

The last line makes no sense honestly. You can't assign `print()` to a variable. It's a function and you don't assign functions to variables. You can only assign classes to variables. That should also be part of your error since `print(enemy_health - power)` actually works. The output is 40.